# IdentityServer4 save and retreive data using UserId

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, identityserver4

IdentityServer4 creates among other tables an AspNetUsers table with userIds, I would like to use these userids to store and retrieve related data.

When I send a request with a bearer token how would I retrieve the userid from the request using the following example;

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]VehicleRequest message)
{
    userId = "?";

    Vechicle vehicle = await _vehicleRepository.AddVehicle(
        message.licensePlate,
        message.make,
        message.model,
        userId);

    return new ObjectResult(vehicle);
}

[Authorize]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetVehicles()
{
    userId = "?";

    IList<Vechicle> vehicles = await _vehicleRepository.GetVehicles(userId);

    return new ObjectResult(vehicles);
}
```

Comment: you use the subject Id to distinguish users or just send the userid as data in the token

Answer (score 0):

The user ID would typically be in the “sub” claim accessible via User.Identity.Claims in your controller action.